# create form with xml in joomla2.5

Tags: xml, joomla

hello
i want create form in joomla2.5(in component)
Like the registration form joomla
tanks

Comment: joomla registration form is not xml file

Comment: in folder model->forms

Comment: joomla registration is component include xml, php, html and etc.
Do you want create custom form in joomla?

Comment: yes and i want make field(for example text box) in file xml in model

Comment: Do you check Joomla form builder directory? : http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/contacts-and-feedback/forms
there are many extention that you can use

Comment: NO,i dont want use extension i want write this extension

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this links shows how to implement a model using the database, the controller, and the view. I think it's a good point to start.

http://docs.joomla.org/Tutorial:Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_Component_-_Part_1

http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_Component/2.5/Adding_backend_actions

form field type: http://docs.joomla.org/Checkbox_form_field_type